# Can't enable Pep8 in Eclipse Luna

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pep8

I am running `Eclipse Luna` with `PyDev` version `3.8.0.201409251235`.

Initially I installed Java 8 on a clean system.  Now I also added Java 7, since PyDev seems to require Java 7 properly.

I can run Django on Eclipse and PyDev seems to be working fine. However no matter what I do, I can't enable Pep8 in `Settings -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis.`

I click on Apply and OK. When I come back, pep8.py is disabled again and `Options` is activated.

Any idea what I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed.  I tried to save the file, and restarted Eclipse several times without success. But no pep8 warnings showed ever up. Once I started refactoring the code, suddenly the pep8 kicked in and showed me all the warnings.  It must be a bug as you said. I leave the question open, in case eclipse devs see that.

Comment: Agree. Its great.  But GAE support is no longer free. :)

Comment: Hey @Hooman , this is solved or not. Because i'm getting this also. PEP8 is not enable.

Comment: see my comment above, it worked automatically down the line.  I have been a fierce Py/Eclipse user for the past few years. But I know I finally have to admit, PyCharm is in every way just better.  Do yourself a favour and instal the free edition and test it out.

Comment: Have look at this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983521/enable-the-pep8-in-eclipse-luna

best regard

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have **init**.py files in all directories
- Project->Properties-> Pydev-Path-> select your sub-directory as source folder
- clean the project, exit eclipse and restart
- Now you should see you folder as a pydev package and click on file and run code
  analysis.You should be able to see the warnings