# Enable pep8 in Eclipse for Remote System Explorer

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, pydev, pep8

Referring to this original post: [Enable pep8 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983521/enable-pep8-in-eclipse/39876251#39876251)

What do you propose can be done to get PEP8 working when using remote file explorer? If possible at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up updating Eclipse to newest version.